# show a string of my div and append

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I show a string representation of my div emptied then append to it?

```
 var x = $('#myDiv').outerHTML(); 
x = x.empty().append('<h1>test</h1>');


//result must look like  <div id="myDiv"><h1>test</h1></div>
```

Comment: var x = $('#myDiv');
x.html('<h1>test</h1>');

Comment: Do you only want to show the id? What if the div also has a class?

Comment: You likely want to use the div from the parent HTML instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the div to a parent.
First create the div you want:

```
var myDiv = $('#myDiv').empty().append("<h1>test</h1>");
```

Add it to a container:

```
var outerHTMLDiv = $("<div></div>").append(myDiv).html();
```

outerHTMLDiv is now

```
 <div id="myDiv"><h1>test</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method of jquery that will `assign html and previous html / text if exists will be removed`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mS7BX/)**

```
$('#myDiv').html('<h1>test</h1>');
```

Answer (score 1):

html() method will override existing data

```
$('#myDiv').html("<h1>asasas</h1>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I have completely misunderstood what you want, or maybe I am not completely nuts. But, here's a `function` I have for you. If I am way off, please comment below and I will delete this answer. That said, here is what I thought you want.

There's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/axebiy/1/edit) also.

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv" class="some_class">Some content already exists</div>
```

End goal: Want to empty the content, in it's place want to show how it would be written in `html` and also append some more text. Your input is the `id` of the element.

Here's the jQuery

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var id_to_change = 'myDiv';
    var content_to_add = '<h1>Test</h1>';
    show_details(id_to_change, content_to_add);
});
```

And here's the function definition

```
function show_details( id, text ){
  var $el = $('#'+id);
  var lt = '&lt;';
  var gt = '&gt;';
  var tag = $el.prop('tagName').toLowerCase();

  // This is messed up, but I dunno how else to do it easily
  $el.text( text );
  var text_with_tags = $el.html();
  $el.text('');

  $el.append(lt+tag);

  var el = document.getElementById(id);  
  for (var attr, i=0, attrs=el.attributes, l=attrs.length; i<l; i++){
    attr = attrs.item(i);
    $el.append(' '+attr.nodeName+'="'+attr.nodeValue+'"');
  }

  $el.append(gt+text_with_tags+lt+tag+gt);
}
```

Once the function runs, the actual contents of the div will be

```
<div class="some_class" id="myDiv"><h1>Test</h1><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
   $("#id").empty().wrapInner('<h1>test</h1>')​​
```