# alert whole div after changing the contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get selected element’s outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)
>   [show a string of my div and append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306107/show-a-string-of-my-div-and-append)

With the code below I need to alert this `<div id="myDiv"><h1>test</h1></div>`

but my code alerts this `<h1>test</h1>`

How do I do this? thanks

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5GCEQ/

```
        <div id="myDiv">

            <div>test</div>
            <div>test</div>
            <div>test</div>
            <div>test</div>
            <div>test</div>
            <div>test</div>
            <div>test</div>

        </div>​
```

---

```
    var s = $('#myDiv').html('<h1>test</h1>');

    alert(s.html()); //alerts <h1>test</h1>

//
//but I want it to alert    <div id="myDiv"><h1>test</h1></div>
//​​​
```

Comment: don't repost your questions, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) in JQuery:

```
var s = $('#myDiv').html('<h1>test</h1>');
alert(s.parent().html());
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feZed/) code.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
alert(s[0].outerHTML);
```